# CDI scopes in non http application

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, mqtt

I am developing a Java EE application with no http interface: it uses only MQTT for sending/receiveing data.

I am wondering whether CDI `@SessionScoped` and `@RequestScoped` apply to this scenario or I have to define custom scopes to handle client's requests.

## Edit

I tried a simple application that injects a `@SessionScoped` or `@RequestScoped` bean in mqtt receive callback and I got an exception saying that I have no active context.

Is it possible to activate a context programmatically so that beans' lifecycle follow the chosen scope?

PS: when I post the question I was not too lazy to make that simple test but I was courious to go deeper in CDI scope theory...and still I am..

Answer (score 5):

There is a possibility you need to create Request or Session context your self.

That is of course CDI implementation and application specific.

For example, if you use Weld and need Request Scope, you can create and activate org.jboss.weld.context.bound.BoundRequestContext.

```
      /* Inject the BoundRequestContext. */

   /* Alternatively, you could look this up from the BeanManager */

   @Inject BoundRequestContext requestContext;


   ...


   /* Start the request, providing a data store which will last the lifetime of the request */

   public void startRequest(Map<String, Object> requestDataStore) {

      // Associate the store with the context and activate the context

      requestContext.associate(requestDataStore);

      requestContext.activate();

   }


   /* End the request, providing the same data store as was used to start the request */

   public void endRequest(Map<String, Object> requestDataStore) {

      try {

         /* Invalidate the request (all bean instances will be scheduled for destruction) */

         requestContext.invalidate();

         /* Deactivate the request, causing all bean instances to be destroyed (as the context is invalid) */

         requestContext.deactivate();

      } finally {

         /* Ensure that whatever happens we dissociate to prevent any memory leaks */

         requestContext.dissociate(requestDataStore);

      }

   }
```

you can found info and this Example here https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/contexts.html

Also for BoundConversationContext.
Session scope is little bit harder, you need a real session support in your application to be able to implement it.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I read the documentation you linked and I found some useful informaion. Unfortunately, I have not yet understood how I am supposed to use the `BoundConversationContext`: should I inject the context in the bean I want to have a request scope and "copy - paste" the code you posted? should I call those methods from my code or are used by the container? should I manage the `requestDataStore`?

Comment: You need to associate and activate scope context before you access your Scoped bean and deactivate it afterwords. That mean you need to do it outside your bean. In your case you can for example create conversation context if some kind of even or data received and  deactivate it after timeout.